# given maxim how to find minima?

Tags: functions

The maximum value of the function $y=\dfrac{1}{(1+|x|)}+\dfrac{1}{(1+|x|-a)}$, is $\dfrac{6}{5}$.Then find the value of $y$ at point of local minima.

I have tried the following thing:

I have derivated the function to get critical value of $x$. I got it in terms of $a$. Then I substituted in the given equation and got value of $a$. The problem I faced was I was getting 1 real value and 1 imaginary value of $a$. So can anybody out there help me out.

Comment: If you don't provide the domain of definition the question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: sorry I am not given that.

Comment: Anyway, assuming $a<1$ so that it's defined everywhere then it won't have any local minimum.

Comment: @cronos2  $a < 1$ is not necessary for the function $y$ to be defined everywhere. Only $a \ne 1$ is required.

Answer (score 1):

The function $y=\dfrac{1}{(1+|x|)}+\dfrac{1}{(1+|x|-a)}$ achieves its maximum value when $x=0$ because *any* other value of $x$ will increase the denominator of the $2$ fractions involved and thereby will decrease the value of $y$. So, we can conclude that the maximum value of $y$ occurs at $x=0$. Hence,
$$1 + \frac{1}{1-a} = \frac{6}{5} \implies a = -4$$

Therefore, 
$$y =\dfrac{1}{(1+|x|)}+\dfrac{1}{(|x|+5)}$$

The plot of the function is shown below and you can see that there is no local minima to this function.[image: plot]

EDIT 1 :
As @Alessandro17 correctly says, $y$ need not be the same as above, but the analysis still holds and there still is no local minima to the function $y$ even if $a$ is allowed negative values.
For example, if $a=3$ the plot looks like this: [image: plot2]

Comment: The first sentence is false. If $a<0$ then clearly the maximum is achieved at $x=0$, but if $a>0$ this does not happen in general. For example if $a=2$ then in $x=0$ the function takes the value $0$ while in $x=2$ it takes the value $1/3+1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the analysis still holds true and the function still does not have any point of local minima.

Comment: If x=0 then a=-4.Then the eqution comes out to be y=2(|x|

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying. How are you concluding $a=-4$? And even if $a=-4$, then also $y \ne 2|x|$.

Comment: im sorry if x=0 thena=-4 since maximum value is 6/5 then  y=1/(1+|x|)+1/(|x|+5) whose graph is at the following link(jst take absolute value of x) .Even this tells that there is no minima.

Comment: https://graphsketch.com/?eqn1_color=1&eqn1_eqn=%282%28x%2B3%29%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B6x%2B5%29&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_eqn=&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_eqn=&eqn4_color=4&eqn4_eqn=&eqn5_color=5&eqn5_eqn=&eqn6_color=6&eqn6_eqn=&x_min=-17&x_max=17&y_min=-10.5&y_max=10.5&x_tick=1&y_tick=1&x_label_freq=1&y_label_freq=1&do_grid=0&do_grid=1&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=850&image_h=525

Comment: Yes you are right. I had committed a careless arithmetic mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.